# Laravel 4 migrations Schema - index length

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I ran into a problem with laravel migration where I need to set index length for a specific column but it looks like Schema/Blueprint index() does not have such feature. [Laravel Docs](http://lukearmstrong.co.uk/docs/laravel4/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_index)

```
      [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
      SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
      1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'description' used in key specification 
      without a key length (SQL: alter table `Customers` 
      add index `description_idx`(`description`))
```

Original sql query line:

```
KEY `description_idx` (`description`(100)) // index length = 100
```

Laravel migration code line:

```
$table->text('description')->nullable()->index('`description_idx`'); // no index length here
```

At moment I feel the best I can do is to change column type, but maybe there is more appropriate way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create these indexes manually using DB::statement(); in your migration.

In your up() do something like this

```
DB::statement('CREATE INDEX description_idx ON Customers (description(100));');
```

And then in your down() you can simply

```
Schema::table('Customers', function($table) {
    $table->dropIndex('description_idx');
});
```

Hope that helps.